# Samey metaphors -v- unlike metaphors

Tags: terminology, metaphors, simile

Often metaphors are likenesses where there's a direct connection.  For example on the news somebody describes a crash/ earthquake/ explosion as *It was like a bomb going off*.

What about where the two things are not similar. *Her painted toe-nails were an explosion of colour.* (Exploding feet anyone!)

This poem **Cherry Ripe** by Thomas Campion is full of insinuations rather than direct likenesses.

> ```
> There is a garden in her face
> Where roses and white lilies blow;
> A heavenly paradise is that place,
> Wherein all pleasant fruits do flow:
> There cherries grow which none may buy
> Till 'Cherry-ripe' themselves do cry.
>
> Those cherries fairly do enclose
> Of orient pearl a double row,
> Which when her lovely laughter shows,
> They look like rose-buds fill'd with snow;
> Yet them nor peer nor prince can buy
> Till 'Cherry-ripe' themselves do cry.
>
> Her eyes like angels watch them still;
> Her brows like bended bows do stand,
> Threat'ning with piercing frowns to kill
> All that attempt with eye or hand
> Those sacred cherries to come nigh,
> Till 'Cherry-ripe' themselves do cry.
> ```

My question is:  Are there technical terms that distinguish between:

(a) Direct likeness.  eg *sky-blue eyes*

(b) Not really like at all. eg *eyes like angels*

(c) Over-arching 'big metaphor'. eg *garden in her face*

Comment: Poetry is the term that covers it all ... figuratively.

Comment: Arguably *Her painted toe-nails were an explosion of colour* is a ***vivid*** or ***striking*** metaphor (not really; it's more a cliche). But it's still a "samey" metaphor. There's no such thing as an "unlike" metaphor - that just means you haven't responded to it the way the speaker / writer intended. Nobody expects you to think the feet are literally exploding!

Comment: So far as I can see, the "cline" for metaphor types here just seems to be from near-literal to highly creative / imaginative. But the near-literal ones aren't really "figurative" in the first place - true metaphors are *supposed* to be a bit outlandish!

Comment: I was always taught that saying "X is like Y" is a _simile_, "X is Y" is a metaphor. Your first example is a simile.

Comment: Metonymy is substituting closely-related things (e.g. head for brain), metaphor unlike things (e.g. clockwork for brain). So that's the your range.

Comment: "sky-blue eyes" isn't a metaphor; "sky" is an attributive noun modifying "blue" to express a particular shade of blue.

Comment: @Kate Linguists class similes as 'metaphors presented in comparative formats' ('crazy like a fox', 'as plain as a pikestaff', 'was as it were a wheel in the middle of a wheel' .... What defines metaphor and instantiations of any type is that a comparison at some specific point is made choosing a generally very different comparator; the point of correspondence is then highlighted. 'John is a tiger' and 'John is like a tiger' are essentially the same metaphor, one in simile form.

Comment: @Stuart 'Sky-blue [eyes]' does use a metaphor even though the dictionaries now define the term in its own right. It may be a dead metaphor, but as a point of comparison is made between two vastly different items (sky and something ... anything ... very much non-sky), a metaphor is involved.

Comment: Nordquist at [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/ways-of-looking-at-a-metaphor-1691815) proposes a list of different types of metaphor. // I'm not sure what you mean by your category b; [John is a tiger] uses the (archetypal fierce, uncompromising, don't-mess-with-me sort, not Tigger) tiger as **vehicle** and John (the lad, not the noun) as **tenor** with the characteristics mentioned (not the long striped tail, say) as **point/s of correspondence**. Are you saying that tenor and vehicle are especially far removed? // Doubtless some creative metaphors are too closely related re ...

Comment: tenor/vehicle ("that lion's a real tiger"), while in some the attempted comparison is pretentious or otherwise spurious ('the baked-bean wind blows mainly on the plain').

Comment: D'you not see the real problem is anyone's inability to see how 'Her painted toe-nails were an explosion of colour' might be an exaggeration, but that exaggeration is broadly the difference between poetry and prose?